# Display an editor in the front end using a module

Tags: module, front-end, editor, editing

I'm trying to display an editor using a module in the front end.
I want visitors to be able to edit and create articles but from a module not a component.

I've tried:

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.editor' );
$editor =& JEditor::getInstance();
echo $editor->display("desc", "my text", "600", "400", "80", "15",1);
```

which I think should work but doesn't  (I've tried with all the versions of editors installed).
Any help would be great.

Comment: I just want to leave a non-resolving, academic note that in accordance with PSR-12, no php application should ever use `=&` as a combined operator, because it is not a combined operator. If you are a developer that is careful about every character in your script, have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403  It is simple to fix by doing a project-wide search&replace through your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem

```
echo JHtml::_('form.csrf');

    jimport( 'joomla.html.editor' );
    
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $global_editor = $config->get( 'editor' );
    
    $user_editor = JFactory::getUser()->getParam("editor");
    
    if($user_editor && $user_editor !== 'JEditor') {
        $selected_editor = $user_editor;
    } else {
        $selected_editor = $global_editor;
    }
    
    $editor = JEditor::getInstance($selected_editor);
    
    $editor_params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
        'style'  => '1' ,
        'layer'  => '0' ,
        'table'  => '0' ,
        'clear_entities'=>'0',
        'mode' => '1',
        'buttons' => 0
    );

echo "<form> ";
    echo $editor->display('editMain', '', '100%', '400', '20', '20', true, null, null, null, $editor_params);
echo JHtml::_( 'form.token' );
 //echo '<input id="token" type="hidden" name="' . JSession::getFormToken($forceNew = true) . '" value="1" />';

echo "</form>";
```

This works .  I was had placed the csfr in the wrong place and once it was in the right place all worked as expected.